# Python ,connect to printer using ip and win32api

Tags: python

I want to print a file using win32api.
I have a network printer using this ip: **192.168.1.50**

So i used this code:

```
import win32api
file_path="test.txt"
win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", file_path, None, ".", 0)
```

How can i print this file on the printer that i don't have the name but the ip?

Comment: What kind of network connectivity does the printer have? Is it an `lpd` printer?

Comment: using 'print' in [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) basically is just the same as right-clicking a file and selecting 'print'. Maybe if you add the printer to your system's printers and set it as default, it may work.

Comment: My printer have a http server that you can enter by the ip but i dont know the connections with windows or other os

Comment: thats the problem @mata i need to have the options to select the printer.